# Stop multiple PCs running same script for generic mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I made a script to auto forward messages (with custom response) and, from what i gathered, it has to be on a running Outlook for it to be working.

The issue is that if a couple of machines are running that script will it "go off" multiple times?

- from specific sender
- containing XYZ in subject
- except when it contains ABC in subject

  ```
  Public Sub FW(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)

  Dim olForward As Outlook.MailItem
  Set olForward = olItem.Forward



      With olForward
          'Stuff happens here that work properly 
       End With

  End If


  '// Clean up
  Set olItem = Nothing
  Set olForward = Nothing

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: The answer is `yes`.  Multiple machine will forward the same email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Barney comment is absolutely correct and multiple runs of the script will trigger multiple forward of the item, I would like to add what you should do to perform your action once.

In the script right after successful forward of the message you should add a custom property into the item. The property will just indicate that the message was already forwarded (may be parsed/touched by your script). Now make the condition for entire item handling and check this property exists. If it does, do not perform any actions. The following resource will help with custom properties: [How To: Add a custom property to the UserProperties collection of an Outlook e-mail item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/19/how-to-add-a-custom-property-to-the-userproperties-collection-of-an-e-mail-item-in-outlook/)